# Como eliminar en android studio algo dibujado en el canvas

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

quisiera saber si se puede eliminar algo dibujado en el canvas. En este ejemplo tengo 2 circulos, el circulo 1 se puede mover mientras que el circulo2 esta estático. Quisiera que cuando los circulos choquen el circulo2 desaparezca. Es posible hacer eso?

Gracias.

```
public class Juego extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

int x = 100;
int y = 100;
int radio = 100;
Paint paint;
int x2, y2;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);
    x2= canvas.getWidth()/2;
    y2=canvas.getHeight()/2;
    canvas.drawCircle(x2, y2, radio, paint1);

    double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y), 2));

    if (dist < radio + radio){

    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event){

    x = (int)event.getX();
    y = (int)event.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Tengo los 2 círculos y mediante una ecuación calcule la distancia el problema es que no se como hacer para borrar uno de los círculos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perdona por el comentario anterior. No se entiende nada.
Si lo que quieres es que desaparezca del todo, yo añadiría una booleana.
public class Juego extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

```
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
int radio = 100;
Paint paint;
int x2, y2;
boolean muere = false;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);

    // Si muere es false se dibuja el circulo verde
    if (!muere) {
        x2 = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
        y2 = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
        canvas.drawCircle(x2, y2, radio, paint1);
    }

    double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y), 2));

    if (dist < radio + radio) {
        // Con muere = true, deja de dibujarse el circulo verde
        muere = true;
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    x = (int) event.getX();
    y = (int) event.getY();

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Con una condición.
If(el círculo 1 no toca el círculo 2) el círculo 2 se dibuja.
Cuando el círculo 1 toque el círculo 2, el círculo 2 no se dibujará.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radio, paint);

    double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y), 2));

    if (la condicion que quieras){
     // Se dibuja el circulo 2
     x2= canvas.getWidth()/2;
     y2=canvas.getHeight()/2;
     canvas.drawCircle(x2, y2, radio, paint1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, funciona. El tema es que yo queria eliminarlo de forma definitiva o que quede en invisible o algo. Queria hacer como un juego y queria que cuando golpee al circulo desaparezca de la pantalla. Eso se puede hacer o tengo que encararlo de otra manera? Gracias

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que desaparezca del todo, yo añadiria una booleana// Si muere es false se dibuja el circulo verde
        if (!muere) {
            x2 = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
            y2 = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
            canvas.drawCircle(x2, y2, radio, paint1);
        }

        double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y), 2));

        if (dist < radio + radio) {
            // Con muere = true, deja de dibujarse el circulo verde
            muere = true;
        }